# txpostgres return last insert from a stored procedure

Tags: python, postgresql, twisted

I am using TxPostgres for insert a row into a postgresql, my stored procedure is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gps_open_connection(
    _ip character varying(15),
    _port integer
) RETURNS integer AS $$ 
DECLARE
    log_id integer;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO gpstracking_device_logs (gpstracking_device_logs.id, gpstracking_device_logs.ip, gpstracking_device_logs.port, gpstracking_device_logs.status, gpstracking_device_logs.created, gpstracking_device_logs.updated) VALUES (DEFAULT, _ip, _port, TRUE, NOW(), NOW()) RETURNING id INTO log_id;
END
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

and this stored procedure is called from a method in a twisted class, my method is

```
def openConnection (self, ip, port):
        self.connection['ip'] = ip
        self.connection['port'] = port
        self.connection['status'] = True 
        self._d.addCallback(lambda _: self._conn.runQuery("select gps_open_connection('%s', '%s')" % (ip, port)))
        self.id ?
```

My issue is that I dont know how to populate self.id, I hope you could help on this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self._conn.runQuery` returns a `Deferred` that will contain query result.

As you return this `Deferred` from callback, next callback value will be the txpostgres Deferred's value.  So, you may write just after previous callback:

```
def setId(val):
   self.id = val[0]['id']
self._d.addCallback(setId)
```